# product short description - WYSIWYG editor is not displayed

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I need to enable wysiwyg Editor in Magento default Product attribute.

attribute name : short_description.

[image]

I have already take necessary steps to enable editor from database but its not working.

```
set is_wysiwyg_enabled = 1 from catalog_eav_attribute table
```

Please let us know if anyone has solution for same. If i can create new attribute than editor will appear but not working with short_description only.

Thanks for advance